# Why ASP.NET API returns 200 OK but Angular app receives 500 error on Chromium-based browsers only?

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an app in production that is throwing 500 errors only in Chromium-based browsers and only for some API methods. This started to happen after Chrome updated to version 76.

The app uses Angular 7.3.6, ASP.NET Web API using .NET 4.7.2, SQL databases, and IIS 10.0. App is running in AWS.

I have tried in Chrome, Opera, and Edge and 500 error shows up.

I have tried in Safari, Firefox and IE and the error is NOT there.

I have tried running the same app using AngularJS version and the same problem happened. The API calls go to the error callbacks of the front-end. I doubt the issue is the front-end.

I have tested the API calls locally and with Postman and they all work fine.

Furthermore, the API methods do write to the DB and update it successfully, and it returns OK (200), but when the request arrives to the front-end it goes to the error callback and it shows as 500 error. I also doubt is the back-end.

Basically, the flow is:

**front-end (sends required data) -> back-end (returns success) -> front-end (receives 500)**

Following is a simple method in which the call WORKS and the method returns successfully (200). But the front-end receives it as 500. When the user clicks a "Submit" button, `updateUserInfo()` is called.

Angular call:

```
updateUserInfo() {

    if ( (!this.editUser.FirstName || this.editUser.FirstName.trim() == "") && (!this.editUser.LastName || this.editUser.LastName.trim() == "") && this.fileToUpload == null)
        Swal.fire("Empty fields", "Input the fields to update.", "info");

    else {

        this.http.post<any>(TalosSettings.talosBaseUri + "Admin/UpdateUserInfo", this.editUser).subscribe(response => {

            this.user.FirstName = response.FirstName;
            this.user.LastName = response.LastName;

            $('#UpdatePictureModal').modal('hide');
            Swal.fire("Your information has been updated!", "", "success");   

      }, error => {

            Swal.fire("Error updating your information", "Please try again, or contact us.", "error");
            console.error("Error updating user info. " + error);

      });
    }
}
```

API, C#:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateUserInfo(UserDataReturnModel model)
{
    User loggedInUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());

    loggedInUser.FirstName = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.FirstName) ? null : model.FirstName.Trim();
    loggedInUser.LastName = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.LastName) ? null : model.LastName.Trim();

    db.SaveChanges();

    model.FirstName = loggedInUser.FirstName;
    model.LastName = loggedInUser.LastName;

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Model:

```
public class UserDataReturnModel
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool FirstLogin { get; set; }
    public SponsorModel Sponsor {get; set;}
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

So again, I doubt the problem is the API itself.

I think it could be the way the API is deployed or some server setting. But we have been deploying the API the same way for a long time now.

I expect to not receive confusing 500 errors. I don't know how else to test this. If you need more info please let me know.

[Example Chrome error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgN3X.png)

[image]

[Example Chrome error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRL2j.png)

[image]

[Example Chrome detailed request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Vvn.png)

[image]

[Example Chrome detailed request cont.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzU2Z.png)

[image]

This is [network trace](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R7Ai_r6TSQb05KDE0jmPLVZPY_roAlhEJiAbiBfDl88/edit?usp=sharing) of an actual call, taken on Chrome. "OMITTED" means I removed the info on purpose.

**Update 1:**

I changed an API endpoint (`GetUserData`) from a POST to a GET (which should have been a GET in the first place anyways) and it works fine. So the issue is happening on POST/PUT calls.

It seems that Angular is complaining about non-GET calls when the data returns from the server. It might be some header option that needs to be set.

**Update 2 and solution:**

I had this code in WebApiConfig.cs, of course with an actual url for prod:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200/", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

The solution was to remove the trailing forward slash. It maybe should not have been there in the first place but it only gave this annoying error after the new Chrome updates version 76, maybe because of new changes to CORS headers.

Comment: You're errors are from `GetUserData` why are you posting code for `UpdateUserInfo` ?

Comment: Chrome recently added some new rules for CORS checks that have caused problems similar to this.  Try disabling the `chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors` flag and running your app again to see if it's related.  See [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/11089651?hl=en) for a bit more information.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing Use FRT to compare success and failure.

Comment: you could try to use remote debugging to debug an ASP.NET application [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @Train the same error happens on both methods. I just showed `UpdateUserInfo` because it is the shorter one.

Comment: @just.another.programmer thank you for this info. But based on everything I read this is only related to extensions making CORS requests, which does not apply in my case.

Comment: Your date value `\"PlannedComplDate\":\"01-Jan-0001\"`. Is that correct? Maybe Chrome is changing the date?

Comment: @Train that is not a correct date but the api call that receives this data does not make use of this value, so I don't care what value it is. But even if Chrome is doing something with it, I wonder why would that cause the issue I am having?                                                                    


Also, it is strange that I am getting 500 but in Chrome, as you can see in the pictures, the "statusText" says OK. I think that's an Angular thing related to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23334).

Comment: It's hard to tell from just the examples you have given. Do you think you could post the code from start to finish with all of the variable outputs?

Comment: @Train I posted more code, please let me know if this helps. I also posted an update. Thank you for your help

Comment: try to use a tool like a fiddler and capture the success and the fail request compare both and find the difference. [link](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)